# Unable to install swirl on version 3.4.1

Tags: r, swirl

I am newbie to R and I am facing this problem below.

1.

```
Install.packages("swirl")
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/ts/syx225mj4fb7ky5_tsxn08vc0000gn/T//RtmprWr2vv/downloaded_packages
```

2.

```
library(swirl)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
```

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Do a web search for "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found" Then tell us why those resources do not apply here.

Comment: install.packages("stringi")